# How to show only non-hidden folders programmatically

Tags: android, file

So I have this simple method that helps list **all** of the files in a directory (hidden **and** non-hidden) and I wish to edit it to display **only non hidden** files.

```
 public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = new File(DirectoryPath);

        //You create an array list
        //The public final field length, which contains the number of components of the array
        file.mkdirs();
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        //list all of the files in the array
        if (files.length == 0)
            //if there are no files, return null
            return null;
        else {
            //if the number of files is greater than 0, add the files and their names
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
        }

        return MyFiles;
```

How can I modify the above code to only display non hidden files?

By the way, inserting a **.** in front of a file name hides the file.

Thank you.

Comment: if you are talking about Linux, hidden files start with a dot `.` this means that you can check the name of the file/folder and inside your `for` don't add them if their name starts with the dot. I'm not sure what happens on windows though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the `isHidden()`. Refer to the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#isHidden()).

```
//if the number of files is greater than 0, add the files and their names
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(!files[i].isHidden()) 
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName()); // Add non hidden files
        }
```